# fullcalendar event title. I don't want it to be repeated on every line

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

if you have an event that lasts for more than one week, fullcalendar repeats event's title on each every line. How can I override that? I need to show the title only once.
[image]

Comment: could you add this feature request to the issue tracker? http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/list thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andreas described, in callback of eventAfterRender we can get rendered element. And the front and tail of the element would have fc-corner-left and fc-corner-right classes. So we can do something like that:

```
eventAfterRender: function (event, element, view) {
    if (!$(element).hasClass('fc-corner-left'))
{
   $(element, "a").text("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `fc-corner-left` this now should be `fc-start`

Comment: And you'll also want to change the replacement like so `$(element, "a").text("\xa0");` otherwise the height of not-the-first-row will not be the same as the first row. `\xa0` is the space character. For some reason a regular space did not work.

Answer (score 1):

oh yes ... some investigation:

hook to [`eventAfterRender`](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventAfterRender/)-handler: `function( event, element, view ) { }`. so, you've got the event, to determine it's start- and end-date, you've got the element, to determine which part of the event is drawn ... now put this information all together, et voilà ...

Comment: I kinda lost here, still can't do

Comment: in eventAfterRender I can get HTMLDivElement, but I don't know how to determine where (in which day) it begins and where it ends...

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to use jquery and try to find the actual event DOM and see how it is constructed and remove/hide the text on all lines except the first. Sorry I don not have an example to post.

Otherwise you would have to go into the core js and find the method buildSkeleton() and find how the text is added and try to put some logic in there.

Answer (score 0):

Titles are rendered in this div

```
fc-event fc-event-hori fc-event-start
```

and following weeks, if part of the same event are rendered without the `fc-event-start` class, like so

```
fc-event fc-event-hori
```

So the best solution is something like this:

```
eventAfterRender: function(event, element, view) {
    if (!$(element).hasClass('fc-event-start'))
        $(element, 'fc-event-title').text('');
    };
}
```